# Can user defaults set in addSuite(named:) be shared between extensions and their host app?

Tags: swift, userdefaults

I have an extension that needs to use some UserDefaults written from my host app. I didn't want to use `UserDefaults(suiteName:)` since it's an optional, so I used the following property from [this article](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/the-power-of-userdefaults-in-swift/):

```
extension UserDefaults {
    static var shared: UserDefaults {
        let combined = UserDefaults.standard
        combined.addSuite(named: appGroupName)
        return combined
    }
}
```

But when I call it in an extension, the values are not present. Is this expected behavior? And am I bound to use the optional `UserDefaults(suiteName:)` when sharing values with extensions?

I haven't found any Apple documentation explaining this topic.

Comment: If you use `UserDefaults(suiteName:)` in your extension do you get a nil value? If not, then the shared container is working. If it is nil then your extension doesn’t have access. Check the spelling and ensure that the app group capability has been added to the extension in Xcode.

Comment: When I call `UserDefaults(suiteName:)?.dictionaryRepresentation()` in the extension's debugger, no matter what string I use for the name, I always get the same 11 values given by `UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation()`. The app group is obtained via a static variable, so I've triple checked both the app and extension have the correct app group as the suite name. However, we have multiple app groups, could this introduce problems even though I'm using the correct one?

Comment: Did you add the app group to the extension target’s capabilities? And the main app target, of course

Comment: Yes to both. I made a new project to test this and it still doesn't work. I guess we're just not supposed to use UserDefaults.standard in app extensions at all? Even if we're adding a suite

Comment: I have used user default suites in other types of extensions without any problems. You should just try and use that. The only way the initialiser will return nil is if something is misconfigured and if that is the case it won’t work anyway. Better to know that something is wrong.